# Bootstrap 4 columns not laying out correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 grid that has one column that is 9 units and one column that is 3 units but the 9 unit column is not taking up 3/4 of the page width as it should.

The html looks like this:

```css
.features-image2 {
  max-width: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-9 ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
          <h4>POWER</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
          <h4>LOVE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
          <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
          <h4>GREEN</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
          <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
          <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <img class="col-sm-3 features-image2" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The screen looks like this (the table should take up 9 columns 3/4 of screen width but it doesn't):

[image]

The effect I am trying to achieve is to centre both the table and the image both vertically and horizontally in the col-3

Comment: instead of `col-sm-3` use `col` only it will automatically cover the remaining width. Though in `col-sm-9` you should have given `col-sm-4` to cover the full width. Since its makes the to column count equal to 12.

Comment: also add `align-items-center` to parent row to set the inner content vertically align center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your layout...

- Use 3 `col-sm-4` to consume 1/3 of the `col-sm-9`
- Dont use the `col-sm-12` class on the image
- Use flexbox and min-height on the container to center vertically
- Change `col-sm-9` to `col-sm-8 offset-sm-1` to center horizontally (optional)

**Demo** http://www.codeply.com/go/DbV50b96vz

```
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center d-flex">
  <div class="row text-center w-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
          <h4>POWER</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
          <h4>LOVE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
          <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
          <h4>GREEN</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
          <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
          <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
        <img class="features-image2" src="//placehold.it/500x800">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ZimSystem that is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

There is a few issues with your implementation:

- 1st: why did you put those 
   tags? they are unnecessary
- 2nd: I
  think it is better to make image a background image of the block, not
  just put it inside.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.features-image2 {
  /*max-width: 140px;
  min-width: 140px;
  width: 140px;*/
}

.block-left{
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.block-right{
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
  background-image: url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjMxMzg3MDI5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTAxODc0Ng@@._V1_UY317_CR31,0,214,317_AL_.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-9 block-left">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
          <h4>POWER</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
          <h4>LOVE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
          <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
          <h4>GREEN</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
          <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
          <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 block-right">
      
    </div>
```